# Disable input on button click in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="email" ng-disabled="button" rquired>
<a class="btn" ng-model="button">edit</a>
```

So basically I want to enable the input field when the button is clicked. I could do this with some javascript but I want to figure out an easy way for this.

The above example does not work. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use ng-click to change the value of `button`:

```js
<input type="text" ng-model="email" ng-disabled="button" required ng-init="button=true">
<a class="btn" ng-click="button=false">enable edit</a>
<a class="btn" ng-click="button=true">disable edit</a>
<a class="btn" ng-click="button=!button">toggle edit</a>
```

Comment: Greate, is there any chance to have the input initally disabled?