# Disable a div after clicking a button using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to disable a div after clicking the button using angularjs.I've tried using ng-disabled attribute in my div.But I'm unable to do this.Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

My html code:

```
 <button style="margin-left: 22px; margin-top: 16px; background-color: #73AD21" ng-click="getHome()">Home</button>

<div style="margin-top: 15px; display: inline-block"
                    ng-repeat="imageSource in imageSources">
                    <img width=40 height=50 style="margin-left: 12px;"
                        ng-src="{{imageSource}}" /> <br> <span
                        style="margin-left: 12px;">{{getFilenameFromPath(imageSource)}}</span>
                </div>
```

My js code:

```
$scope.imageSources = [];
    $scope.imageSources.push('images/Open.png');
    $scope.imageSources.push('images/New.jpg');
    $scope.imageSources.push('images/Save.png');

    $scope.getFilenameFromPath = function(filename) {
        return filename.split("/")[1].split(".")[0];
    }
$scope.getHome = function() {

        window.location = "./Home.html";
    }
```

Comment: Why not use ng-show/hide or ng-if?

Comment: What do you want to achieve really, what you tried

Comment: Actually,I'm using the same header for 3 different pages.For some pages I want to disable one of the div's and the remaining should be kept active.So,I'm not using show/hide option over here.

Comment: Please see similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733299/disable-input-on-button-click-in-angularjs

You can use a binary variable. Very straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

html file I added `ng-class={'disabled':isClicked}`

```
 <button style="margin-left: 22px; margin-top: 16px; background-color: #73AD21" ng-click="getHome()" ng-class={'disabled':isClicked}>Home</button>

<div style="margin-top: 15px; display: inline-block"
                    ng-repeat="imageSource in imageSources">
                    <img width=40 height=50 style="margin-left: 12px;"
                        ng-src="{{imageSource}}" /> <br> <span
                        style="margin-left: 12px;">{{getFilenameFromPath(imageSource)}}</span>
                </div>
```

in js I added one proeperty isClicked

```
$scope.imageSources = [];
    $scope.imageSources.push('images/Open.png');
    $scope.imageSources.push('images/New.jpg');
    $scope.imageSources.push('images/Save.png');

    $scope.getFilenameFromPath = function(filename) {
        return filename.split("/")[1].split(".")[0];
    }

$scope.isCliked =  false;

$scope.getHome = function() {

        $scope.isClicked = !$scope.isClicked;
        window.location = "./Home.html";
    }
```

and I also added one css class .disabled

```
.disabled{
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

when you click isClicked become true and button element add .disabled class

Comment: I've tried using the above suggested code,but unable to disable the div.I'm not getting where I'm going wrong

Comment: I'm trying to disable the "imageSources" div soon after clicking on the home button

Comment: you can add ng-class={'disabled':isClicked} this on "imageSources" div

Comment: No,I'm unable to disable the div even after adding ng-class={'disabled':isClicked}  on "imageSources" div